# How do I prop-up or fix a concrete post that has moved away from house with gate attached?

Tags: gate-post

I have a two-gate wide opening on the side of my house.

There is a concrete gate post that is next to the house which has pulled away from the house near the top, so that the gates are harder to open.

What is the best way to "shift" the concrete post back towards the house so that the gates swing freely?

Comment: it might just go back in a few months. Unless it's really crooked, i would adjust the latch hardware.

Comment: Do you suppose that you could post a couple of pics, so that we can see how bad it's leaning and the surroundings, etc?

Comment: Also, do you know what has caused the post to lean? I'm thinking that the reason why it moved in the first place would have an effect on how to fix it..or if the fix will be permanent or temporary. Are you in a part of the world that would be subject to frost heaving? Is the weight of the gate(s) causing it to lean?

Answer (score 0):

I would remove material from the side closest to the house, then use a jack to push the post back upright.

Once upright, you will need to fill in the subsequent gap on the gate side. Concrete would be good, and consider opening the hole to increase the support all around that gate post.